# .net 4.0 on iis7 with WCF app showing NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2005, iis-7, .net-4.0

> Dot net 4.0
>
> IIS7
>
> WCF app
>
> SQL 2005 standard

App is hosted on server1 , db is hosted on server2.

Application pool using .4.0 integrated as opposed to classic.

When browsing to site i see NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON.

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out.

Removed 

Integrated Security=true

From web.config.

Appear the application pool identity was being passed to SQL server. Removing integrated security from web.config resolved. Sorry about that.

Comment: Then you'd better make your comment an answer and mark it as Accepted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, just figured it out.

Removed

Integrated Security=true

From web.config.

Appears the application pool identity was being passed to SQL server.